# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') at Router

Tags: path, runtime-error, typeerror

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
at Router

-``This is my **app.js code**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";

function App() {
return (

      <div className="App">
        <Router>
        <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          
          </Routes>
        </Router>`
      </div>

);
}
export default App;
```

this is my **index.js** file don't know reason behind error

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
\<React.StrictMode\>
\<App /\>
\</React.StrictMode\>
);
```